# Price of products have a % up in the final price

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem with a products of my store because if I have a product with price 889€ in the website I see 1075.

All products have a 12% up of inital price.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin pannel , check at the products "tax".
I think that it is

Comment: Yeah, I have a 21% of iniital price for a country. Thank you!